# Fix Custom Calendar View Issue

Tags: android

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.CalendarView
import android.widget.TextView
import java.util.*

class CustomCalendarView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : CalendarView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        // Customize the appearance or behavior as needed
        setOnDateChangeListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            // Handle date change event
            val selectedDate = getDate(year, month, dayOfMonth)
            // Your custom logic to highlight or decorate the selected date
            highlightDate(selectedDate)
        }
    }


    private fun highlightDate(date: Long) {
        // Your custom logic to highlight or decorate the specified date
        // For example, change the background color or add a special marker

        // Get the day view for the specified date
        val dayView = getChildAt(0) as? TextView
        // Customize the appearance (example: change background color)
        dayView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
    }


    private fun getDate(year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int): Long {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        return calendar.timeInMillis
    }



    fun clearHighlights() {
        // Your custom logic to clear any highlighted or decorated dates
        // For example, reset the background color or remove markers

        // Reset the background color of all day views
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val dayView = getChildAt(i) as? TextView
            dayView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }

    private fun getDayOfMonth(date: Long): Int {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = date
        return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    }






    // Additional methods can be added to customize the calendar further
}
```

I am new to using custom versions of views, the app doesn't allow the custom view to be loaded giving the error

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(int, int, int,
> int)' on a null object reference at
> android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeekView.drawSelectedDateVerticalBars(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1525)
> at
> android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeekView.onDraw(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1406)
> at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23466)"

, the custom view works in the build simulator for a few seconds and then stops working

I tried some adjustments to the code but it didn't fix it. The problem may be obvious

Answer (score 0):

I bet your obtained `dayView` have, by default, some `Drawable` set for background, and some other code (in framework) is basing on it, trying to cast `Drawable` from background, which isn't present, because you've pasted just color and "default one" is gone..

(color should be converted internally to `ColorDrawable`, but there is a chance that `setBackgroundColor` is removing previous drawable, but storing only `int` of color, and next frame draw will prepare `ColorDrawable` - in this very short time window there may be a chance for such NPE, looks like "LegacyDelegate" isn't ready for proposed background changes)

resolution would be to not changing background drawable, use `tint`ing methods, like [setBackgroundTintList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))
(and e.g. `ColorStateList.valueOf(..)`), or manipulate existing attached `Drawable` obtained through [`getBackground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getBackground())